# How to Add Scrollbar to Minicart Dropdown Content in Magento 2.1.x

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart

Currently, when 5+ products are added to Cart and a user clicks on the minicart icon, so that the dropdown is initialized - the dropdown contents go beyond screen fold, effectively hiding a portion of itself.

The minicart icon is fixed on a sticky top menu, so that when the screen is scrolled down, the hidden minicart dropdown contents stay beyond the screen fold. It's ugly and very user unfriendly.

I wonder what would be the best way to add scrollbar to the minicart dropdown and make the minicart dropdown content scrollable after, say, 5 items have been added to it? Or, make the contents scrollable after a certain pixel length of the dropdown is exceeded? What would the JS code be for achieving this?

How can I make the minicart dropdown content scrollable?

[image: Magento 2.1 scrollable minicart]

I have a Magento 2.1.9 instance. All teaching is welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a default configuration for that under

> System -> Configuration -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart Sidebar

and then the option **Number of Items to Display Scrollbar**

Comment: Lovely. That's what I had in mind. Thanks!  P.S. I have to say I did searched for an answer before posting here, but I guess my question formulation didn't gave me the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.2.x

> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart Sidebar